# Postgresql: CASE statement inside STRING_AGG() loops forever

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to execute a (postgresql) query the auto-generates the INSERT statement for a table dynamically, for test data. I am using a SWITCH CASE statement to decide which value to return based on the column's type.

Anyone know why the following SQL query seems to execute indefinitely (or at least, for a very, very long time).

```
select  STRING_AGG(
            CASE 
                WHEN (udt_name = 'timestamptz' OR udt_name = 'timestamp' OR udt_name = 'date')     THEN
                    '1990-02-02'
                WHEN (udt_name = 'text')                             THEN
                    --text value as long as length of column
                    schema_a.make_text_value(character_maximum_length) -- returns value instantly
                WHEN (udt_name = 'numeric')                         THEN
                    null
                WHEN (udt_name = 'bit')                             THEN
                    null
                WHEN (udt_name = 'bool')                             THEN
                    null
                WHEN (udt_name = 'int4')                             THEN
                    null
                ELSE null
            END
        , ','
        ) cols 
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS col2
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='schema_a' 
AND col2.TABLE_NAME='big_event' -- big_event has 4 columns
LIMIT 1
```

The stored procedure called is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema_a.make_text_value(loopMax integer)
RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE
        loopCounter INTEGER := 1;
        val TEXT := '';
BEGIN
LOOP
    EXIT WHEN loopCounter = loopMax ;
    val := val || 'A';
    loopCounter := loopCounter  + 1; 
END LOOP;
-- CONCAT('version_id' , CAST(idCounter AS TEXT)),
-- '2020-08-28 13:25:00.123456'
RETURN val;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Comment: It's a case _expression_ not a statement.

Comment: You don't actually need a stored function (not a "procedure") to begin with. a simple `rpad('A', character_maximum_length, 'A')` will achieve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `loopMax` is `NULL`, it can never be equal to `loopCounter`. So now let's look at [the definition for `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns.character_maximum_length`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/infoschema-columns.html):

> If data_type identifies a character or bit string type, the declared maximum length; null for all other data types **or if no maximum length was declared**.

(emphasis mine)
It certainly seems possible for this value to be `NULL`, based on that definition. Of course, you know your own schema, so you might be able to show this never happens... but I'd triple check to be sure, and maybe add a *well-considered* guard around the `loopMax` value anyway; you probably don't want to concatenate two **billion** strings in that situation.